# NSTask start/stop

Tags: objective-c, button, nstask

I'm currently trying to start NSTask on button click and stop it on another button click (two buttons).
Can anybody tell my how to do that?

Thanks, Greets
Julian

Comment: Ouh!
I forgot to declare the NSTask in the header file… *shame on me*
So now it works! Thanks, Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send it a `-launch` message when you want it to start, and send it a `-terminate` message when you want it to stop.

Is there something you're not understanding in the documentation?